# Can't get any Discord Messages from Users

Tags: c#, discord, console, bots

*Hey folks,*

long story short : I've written this line of code in my C# Console-Program

```
private async Task ClientOnMessageReceived(SocketMessage socketMessage)
{
    if (!socketMessage.Author.IsBot)
    {    
        var channel_msg = _client.GetChannel(Convert.ToUInt64(_channelIdSky2)) as SocketTextChannel;
        var discordMessages = await channel_msg.GetMessagesAsync(20).FlattenAsync();
        var orderedMessages = discordMessages.OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var msg in orderedMessages)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(msg.Author + ":\r\n" + msg.Content + "\r\n");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
    return;
}
```

I am getting the following Ouput :

[image]

[image]

**Why the Script can only read Bot Messages and no user messages?**

> if (!socketMessage.Author.IsBot)

isn't the error. i've tried it without

Would really hope for Your help.

Best greetings from Germany

*CMeow*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you enable the **Message Content Intent** on the Discord Developer Portal, because it is a privileged intent and needs to be explicitly set.

[image: discord developer portal - message content intent]

Additionally, you need to go into your `DiscordSocketConfig` and add the `MessageContent` intent to the `GatewayIntents` property. If you don't have a `DiscordSocketConfig`, create one and pass it into the constructor of your `DiscordSocketClient`.

Example:

```cs
var config = new DiscordSocketConfig
{
    GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.AllUnprivileged | GatewayIntents.MessageContent
}            };
```

> Note: You should specify the intents you actually need instead of defaulting to `All` or `AllUnprivileged`

Comment: Do you mean i should add " GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.MessageContent " in the configs.

Comment: and any other intents you require, yes