# Looking for Clarifications on SocketMessages and listening to channel in server bot belongs to

Tags: c#, discord.net

So I have a pretty extensive discord.net bot. The bot portion is really just going to be a place for the messages to be posted, but ultimately it queries multiple public APIs, deserializes the JSON response, then I do various tasks with the outcome data.

All of this is working just fine, and in fact, it posts to the correct channel, and I am able to swap in parameters for the data returned, etc. The intention of the bot is just to post information as it's updated from a composite of 4 sites that have public, queryable APIs. But this question is just for the wandering mind.

I basically mirrored this code for a simple test:

```
   private static Task ClientOnMessageReceived(SocketMessage arg)
{
    if (arg.Content.StartsWith("!helloworld"))
    {
        arg.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Message Response");
    }
```

Now, the question is, if I send that same !helloworld in a channel, that the bot has access to, it does not respond to it. If I @ my bot, it does not respond to it. It will only respond or even indicate that it's listening for DMs. Why? Does the SocketMessage object only work for DMs? If so, how would I listen to the text channels on a particular server and respond whenever any person says '!helloworld', the use for this is not one that I need for the bot. I just want to understand what I am missing. Ideally, I would want to see if someone says a funky phrase, so I can toss out a funkier response just for fun, however even in just my testing I can't figure it out.

So any help would be greatly appreciated, I thought I had a decent grasp on this library, but I am just not connecting the dots on this.

Comment: With the new version of the Discord API, the `MessageContent` intent is required for the bot to receive the content data for a message **unless** the bot is tagged in that message (then it gets the data regardless of the intent being enabled or not). If you debug your code you'd see that your response isn't being sent because `arg.Content` is empty when a non tagged message is received. Additional info on setting and using the intent [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73937627/11159372)

Comment: Thank you, and to be clear, a DM would be treated the same as a tagged message? If so, then why does this code here reply to a DM but not a tagged message within a channel that the bot has access to?

Comment: You would have to debug the code and see. There isn't anything much there to go off of. There are intents for GuildMessges and DirectMessages just as the previously mentioned MessageContent. Maybe you don't have them set in your SocketClientConfig.

Answer (score 0):

I logged into the discord developers here and then I added the privileged gateway intents > enabled this and the message content intent. I then add the following to my code before I initialized my discord socket:

```
  public static DiscordSocketConfig config = new DiscordSocketConfig() {
    GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.All };

private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client = new DiscordSocketClient(config);
```

Since this bot is quite literally for myself and my friends, I do not need to worry about the 100 server threshold, unless folks start asking how I get all those cool deal histories and active deals posted in my server! Thanks!