# Discord.Net Message content intent not working

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am fairly new to making a discord bot. My goal was to have it read messages and respond to certain words.
From what I have read, "As of August 31, 2022, access to message content will become a Privileged Intent"; "**This change affects only verified bots, bots that are in 100 or more servers.** Unverified bots in fewer than 100 servers are not affected at all."; "Unverified bots may use Privileged Intents freely."
So if I understand this correctly, as long as I have the "MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT" enabled under the "Privileged Gateway Intents" in the discord developer portal, I should have access to message content; however, the message content comes up empty. The bot will only be used in one server, and that is my own personal server.

```cs
using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;

namespace Core
{
    class Program
    {
        private DiscordSocketClient _client;

        public static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        public async Task MainAsync()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            
            _client.Log += Log;
            _client.MessageReceived += CommandHandler;

            //  You can assign your bot token to a string, and pass that in to connect.
            //  This is, however, insecure, particularly if you plan to have your code hosted in a public repository.
            var token = File.ReadAllText("token.txt");

            // Some alternative options would be to keep your token in an Environment Variable or a standalone file.
            // var token = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NameOfYourEnvironmentVariable");
            // var token = File.ReadAllText("token.txt");
            // var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AConfigurationClass>(File.ReadAllText("config.json")).Token;

            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
            await _client.StartAsync();

            // Block this task until the program is closed.
            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private Task Log(LogMessage msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        //Issue here
        private Task CommandHandler(SocketMessage msg)
        {
            if (msg.Author.IsBot) return Task.CompletedTask;

            msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync(msg.Content);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't seem to find an answer as most of what I have found only applied to verified bots. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The answer is the same for both verified and unverified bots. They only difference with verified bots is that they can't toggle the option in developer portal themselves, it has be be approved by Discord. As for your issue, you also need to set the intents you want via the `DiscordSocketConfig`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73937627/11159372

Comment: Right on! I cant believe it was that simple. It's working perfectly now thanks!