# Discord bot not sending messages Discord.net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.net

my discord bot isnt sending any messages when i type "!hello" even though all documentation online should is saying that it is correct and i followed a tutorial that showed it working. Could anybody help me?

I am using discord.net 3.8.1, (the latest as of right now) and dotnet sdk version 7.0.100

```
using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace discorddotnet
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        private DiscordSocketClient _client;
        public async Task MainAsync()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            _client.MessageReceived += CommandHandler;
            _client.Log += Log;

            //  You can assign your bot token to a string, and pass that in to connect.
            //  This is, however, insecure, particularly if you plan to have your code hosted in a public repository.
            var token = File.ReadAllText("token.json");

            // Some alternative options would be to keep your token in an Environment Variable or a standalone file.
            // var token = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NameOfYourEnvironmentVariable");
            // var token = File.ReadAllText("token.txt");
            // var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AConfigurationClass>(File.ReadAllText("config.json")).Token;

            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
            await _client.StartAsync();

            // Block this task until the program is closed.
            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private Task Log(LogMessage msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private Task CommandHandler(SocketMessage message)
        {
            //variables
            string command = "";
            int lengthOfCommand = -1;

            //filtering messages begin here
            if (!message.Content.StartsWith('!')) //This is your prefix
                return Task.CompletedTask;

            if (message.Author.IsBot) //This ignores all commands from bots
                return Task.CompletedTask;

            if (message.Content.Contains(' '))
                lengthOfCommand = message.Content.IndexOf(' ');
            else
                lengthOfCommand = message.Content.Length;

            command = message.Content.Substring(1, lengthOfCommand - 1).ToLower();

            //Commands begin here
            if (command.Equals("hello"))
            {
                message.Channel.SendMessageAsync($@"Hello {message.Author.Mention}");
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73937627/11159372) should solve it

Comment: @Anu6is No, now im getting

 ```22:22:28 Gateway     You're using the GuildScheduledEvents gateway intent without listening to any events related to that intent, consider removing the intent from your config.```

```22:22:28 Gateway     You're using the GuildInvites gateway intent without listening to any events related to that intent, consider removing the intent from your config.``` 

in my terminal and the bot still sends nothing.

Comment: 1. Those messages just say you specified intents that you aren't using (like I said in the linked answer you should ideally only specify what you need). That not an issue though, just a warning. 2. Debug your code and identify where exactly it's failing. If you didn't specify message content intent you wouldn't get past the first if in the command handler. Where does your execution stop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get any Discord Messages from Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73935914/cant-get-any-discord-messages-from-users)

Answer (score 0):

I got on the same problem but I solve it.

you need to set your `GatewayIntents` into all in your `DiscordSocketConfig()`

the code:

```
    var config = new DiscordSocketConfig()
    {
        GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.All | GatewayIntents.MessageContent
    };
```