# My discord bot won't respond to commands in a server but responds to commands in private messages?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

this is my code
program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;


namespace bot_el_rojla
{
    class Program
    {
        private DiscordSocketClient client;
        private CommandService commands;
        static void Main(string[] args)=> new Program().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        
        public async Task RunBotAsync()
        {
            client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig
            { 
                LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug
            });
            commands = new CommandService();
            client.Log += Log;
            client.Ready += () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("je suis pret");
                return Task.CompletedTask;

            };
            await InstallCommandsAsync();
            await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, "mytoken is here");
            await client.StartAsync();
            await Task.Delay(-1);
            

        }
        public async Task InstallCommandsAsync()
        {
            client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
            await commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), null);
        }
        private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage pMessage)
        {
            var message = (SocketUserMessage)pMessage;
            if (message == null) return;
            int argPos = 0;
            if (!message.HasCharPrefix('!', ref argPos)) return;
            var context = new SocketCommandContext(client,message);
            var result = await commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, null);
            if (!result.IsSuccess) 
                await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result.ErrorReason);
        }
        private Task Log(LogMessage arg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arg.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

commands.cs a class i created

```
using Discord.Commands;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace bot_el_rojla.Modules
{
    public class Commands : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        [Command("ping")]
        public async Task PingAsync()
        {
            await ReplyAsync("pong!");
        }
    }
}
```

if i try the ping command on my server the bot doesnt respond, while it responds to a private message
where did i go wrong?
the logs from console :
14:59:43 Discord     Discord.Net v3.8.1 (API v10)
14:59:43 Gateway     Connecting
14:59:43 Gateway     Connecting ApiClient
14:59:44 Rest        GET gateway/bot: 523.34 ms
14:59:45 Gateway     Received Hello
14:59:45 Gateway     Heartbeat Started
14:59:45 Gateway     Identifying
14:59:45 Gateway     Sent Heartbeat
14:59:45 Gateway     Sent Identify
14:59:45 Gateway     Received HeartbeatAck
14:59:45 Gateway     Latency = 219 ms
14:59:45 Gateway     Received Dispatch (READY)
14:59:45 Gateway     GuildDownloader Started
14:59:45 Gateway     You're using the GuildScheduledEvents gateway intent without listening to any events related to that intent, consider removing the intent from your config.
14:59:45 Gateway     You're using the GuildInvites gateway intent without listening to any events related to that intent, consider removing the intent from your config.
14:59:45 Gateway     Connected
14:59:45 Gateway     Raising Event
14:59:45 Gateway     Received Dispatch (GUILD_AVAILABLE)
14:59:45 Gateway     Connected to Wicked Society
14:59:45 Gateway     GuildDownloader Stopped
je suis pret
14:59:45 Gateway     Ready

Answer (score 0):

oh never mind i found the solution i added GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.All to my websocket configs thanks to this [Can't get any Discord Messages from Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73935914/cant-get-any-discord-messages-from-users/73937627#73937627) :D