# Discord bot having not getting message contents when received from a guild

Tags: c#, async-await, discord, discord.net

I have a normal discord bot (not a self-bot) in C# using the Discord.NET library.
When the bot gets a message, it writes it out in the console:

```
public static async Task MessageReceivedAsync(SocketMessage message)
    {
        if (message.Author.Id != 1206939510382919700)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"({DateTime.Now}) {message.Author.Username} ({message.Author.Id}) @ {message.Channel}: {message.Content} ");
            var channel = message.Channel;
            SendReply(channel, message);
        }
    }
```

And calls a different function that replies to the user:

```
   public static async Task SendReply(ISocketMessageChannel channel, SocketMessage message) 
    {
        await channel.SendMessageAsync($"Message recieved from {message.Author.Username} in {message.Channel}. Message Content {message.Content}");

    }
```

Quite simple, but this works well only when the bot is messaged via DM. When the message is in a server that the bot is a part of, it get the message, but the message itself contains everything but the contents, meaning that I can get what channel it was posted in and by who, but not what.
the reply should look like this:

> Message received from //me in @ //my DM. Message Content: hhh
> but it looks like this
> Message received from //me in General. Message Content:
> I have the Message Content Intent enabled in the Discord Dev Portal.
> Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I have the Gateway intent set up. I have a DiscordSocketConfig with the GatewayIntent.MessageContent in the code and I have the Message Content Intent enabled. I even created a new bot and it does the same. The bot can read the content of its own message, however I assume this is intentional and does not require the privileged intent.

Comment: you need to enable the [message content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73937627/11159372) intent in the developer portal and in your code